# Database detach and attach error

Tags: sharepoint-server

I was trying to do a database migration from one server to another server. So in my development server i first did a trial. Now since this was a trial before it goes to production im now suppose to roll back and keep the dev configuration as it is. So to achieve this. I did the following:

1. Stop all sharepoint services.
2. Iisreset /stop.
3. Attached the dev DB server using SQL.
4. TCL/IP config checked the server details.
5. Start all sharepoint services
6. Start iisreset

Now there is 3 issues after this.

1. Central admin opened fine. But no configurations im able to do. Including creating a new web application.

ERROR MESSAGE: THE NETWORK PATH NOT FOUND.

2. Site is not opening with default.aspx page. I went to sharepoint designer and opened the page defauly.aspx and did a web checkout check in. But still not working. But other pages also not opening as such.
3. The subsites are not upto dated once. There was a major subsite created in development which is missing in this site content section. BUT WHEN I CHECKED THE DATABASE OF THIS DEV SERVER IN TABLE ALLWEBS I CAN SEE THE SUBSITE ALREADY EXISTS THERE. BUT ITS JUST NOT READING.

Additional error messages from Log is for reference:

SqlError: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 53 State: 0 Class: 20 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 0 Server: ''

Comment: Kindly please help.. Need to fix this tommorow it self. Since its out development environment which has major projects

Comment: Check the [connectivity between app server and DB server](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/28/check-sql-server-instance-connectivity/), and make sure that the farm account has dbcreator and security admin as a server role and owner for all Sharepoint database.

Comment: Check permissions on the DB.  detach and reattach to the DB to the farm (This will also set permissions correctly if the farm Account has the right ones). Also which DBs are you talking about? Additional TS: Connect to the SQL Server from any remote SSMS -> Fails? Checked the SQL to allow remote connections

Comment: Are you migrating all database from one Sql server to other? Did you created a sql alias when you point database in dev farm to new server?

Answer (score 0):

The error “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.” indicates that it is not possible to connect to MSSQL Server and it is not possible to connect to SharePoint database.

You could follow the troubleshoot steps in the article below.

[Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine)

And there are three articles below to move databases in SharePoint 2013, you could refer to.

[Move all databases in SharePoint 2013.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx)

[Moving SharePoint Databases to Another Server (Without Reconfiguring SharePoint).](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2014/06/10/moving-sharepoint-databases-to-another-server-without-reconfiguring-sharepoint/)

[Migrate SharePoint’s SQL Server to another SQL Server (same or new version).](http://www.macaalay.com/2013/02/13/migrate-sharepoints-sql-server-to-another-sql-server-same-or-new-version/)